# error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'selectedCategory.title') . does anyone know how to solve this issue? am I using old syntax?

Tags: react-native

**this is my code:**

```
 import React from "react";
    import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, Platform } from "react-native";

    import { CATEGORIES } from "../data/dummy-data";
    import Color from "../constants/Color";
```

**these are all my imports**

```
    const CategoryMealScreen = (props) => {
```

**this is the main function**

```
     const catId = props.navigation.getParam("categoryId");

      const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);
```

*selected category is a constant that is used in text*

```
      return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
          <Text>The Category Meal Screen!</Text>
          <Text>{selectedCategory.title}</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Details"
            onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.navigate({
            routeName: "MealDetail",
          });
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go Back"
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.pop();
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

CategoryMealScreen.navigationOptions = (navigationData) => {
  const catId = navigationData.navigation.getParam("categoryId");

  const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

  return {
    headerTitle: selectedCategory.title,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? Color.primaryColor : "",
    },
    headerTintColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? "white" : Color.primaryColor,
  };
};
```

**this is the styles sheet that i am using**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default CategoryMealScreen;
```

**i guess the problem is from the varibale selected category but i do not know how to solve it**
**please help**

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is not an object in your `selectedCategory` variable. The most obvious cause would be that your `find` is not turning up a match.

If you console.log your `CATEGORIES` from your dummy data, and your `catId` from params, you should be able to see what's wrong. Probably either the catId is missing or there isn't a category that has that ID.